# SSH keys and Active Directory

Tags: 18.04, ssh, active-directory

I am trying to figure out a way of stopping disabled users (in AD) from accessing a specific server with their ssh keys. I have multiple users who can access the server however few of them have setup ssh keys for easy and automatic access for purposes of scripts. From my understanding if a user is disabled in AD they can still log into that server with an old SSH key. Is there a way of automatically removing those keys once the user becomes disabled in AD ? (I use SSSD for authentication if this makes it any easier)